# When to use hurt vs hurts

Tags: word-choice

So, recently I was thinking of texting:

> wao that's nice! Celebrations doesn't hurts .

I am confused if 'hurts' is correct? Or should I use 'hurt'?
I finally wrote 'hurts' and just to be on the safe side reframed the sentence to:

> wao that's nice! Celebrations doesn't hurts anyone

But I am still confused. Please help me with the correct usage of the word 'hurts' vs hurt'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to realize that a verb can be either

- [finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_verb) (= matches the number of the subject of the sentence) or
- [nonfinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-finite_verb) (= no inflection), which are infinitive, participles and gerunds. We are dealing with the infinitive in your example.

For an independent clause (AKA "sentence") you need *at least* one finite verb and unless you are making a "list" ("She *laughs* and *sings* and *dances*.") you use *only one* finite verb.

Very simple sentences use only one verb, which by definition must be finite.:

> This *hurts*.

If you negate the sentence, you use an auxiliary verb (-> *do*, finite) + not, together with the original verb in the infinitive:

> This *does* not hurt
>   -> This *doesn’t* hurt.

Which means you have done a bit too much when inflecting both verbs and the correct phrasing is:

> Celebrations don’t hurt anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't disagree with Stephie's answer. I just have a slightly different way of explaining.

> **Celebrations doesn't hurts**.

The above sentence is incorrect in two different ways.

1. Celebrations is plural. Therefore 'hurts' is wrong. Only the third person singular take 's' in English, thus:

> Celebration hurts. (correct)
>
> Celebrations hurts. (incorrect)

2. When you use the auxiliary verb 'to do', you conjugate 'to do' and you use the bare infinitive of the main verb. The bare infinitive of 'to hurt' is 'hurt'.

> Celebration does hurt. (correct)
>
> Celebrations do hurt. (correct)
>
> Celebration does hurts. (incorrect)
>
> Celebrations do hurts. (incorrect)